# DataTable "depth" in DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, xsd, dataset

I have xsd file, then I create `DataSet` from this file using `DataSet.ReadXmlSchema`. All `DataTable` of this `DataSet` have relationship - `ParentRelation` and `ChildRelation`. I need tree/trees from this `DataTable` with "depth".  Fore example if `DataTable` without parent but have child - it "general" and depth is 0, for all child of this `DataTable` - depth 1 and etc.
I need this construction for parsing large xml file (generate insert instruction).